# Haskell - Cabal Install parsec errors

Tags: haskell, cabal, parsec

I've been trying to install the parsec library for haskell but I'm running in to a lot of errors. Im very new to haskell & cabal and i don't quite understand the output of the log file.

the output of the log file is here:
http://pastebin.com/6hPQN1W4

I tried installing the packages that the log file said that it could not find, but i keep getting errors when trying to install the packages.

I reinstalled cabal and also ran cabal update, but this did not resolve the issue

any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `stack` tool with its stackage infrastructure. Please see http://haskellstack.org for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing `parsec` in a sandbox.

```
$ mkdir asdf
$ cd asdf
$ cabal sandbox init
cabalWriting a default package environment file to
/Users/steshaw/Projects/asdf/cabal.sandbox.config
Creating a new sandbox at /Users/steshaw/Projects/asdf/.cabal-sandbox
$ cabal install parsec
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
/Users/steshaw/Projects/steshaw/asdf/.cabal-sandbox
Configuring mtl-2.2.1...
Configuring text-1.2.2.1...
Building text-1.2.2.1...
Building mtl-2.2.1...
Installed mtl-2.2.1
Installed text-1.2.2.1
Configuring parsec-3.1.11...
Building parsec-3.1.11...
Installed parsec-3.1.11
```